# How to get this Toggle Button Menu to work in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, button, toggle

Thanks to help of the stackoverflow community I had achieved a functioning Toggle Button Menu.

It works in static html pages but when I am trying to replicate within wordpress I am not succeeded although I added the javascript, html and css. I am using WP bakery, added the html using the raw html block, added the javascript using the raw javascript block and the css to the sitewide css. Can someone help please? Thanks

I added all script to wordpress but the toggle functionality does not work...

Comment: This is the code I am referring to https://jsfiddle.net/yf1hd30o/

Comment: Hi and welcome here. Please edit your post with the full contents of your code, not a link to an external resource.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, wanted to let you know that I solved this. I had to move the javascript to beneath the html.